# Multiple Domains on an Exchange Server

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

When I create a new user in exchange, it asks me to provide the User Logon Name.  There is a dropdown box that supposedly allows you to select a domain for the user's login.  What is this referring to?  How can I make it so that I can create users with different domains in their user logon name?

p.s. I am very aware of 'Accepted Domains' in Exchange allowing one user to have several email addresses in different domains.  I am just curious how I can modify the user's Logon name specifically.[image]

Comment: Because that is the active directory domain, not email.

Comment: I've never used the interface you're using but that looks like a field for the UPN suffix (User Principal Name) which is related to Active Directory, not Exchange. You can have multiple UPN suffixes per AD domain but you would have had to have created them for them to be available as a selection. If you want to add UPN suffixes that match your email domains then you can create them and then select the appropriate one when creating the users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, the last part of the User logon name is not an email domain.

The logon name, or User Principal Name, is made up of a user part (usually the same as the users SamAccountName) and a UPN suffix.

UPN suffixes are defined in Active Directory at the forest level, and you can add new UPN suffixes pretty easily, given that you have an Enterprise Administrator account in the forest:

- Open Active Directory Domains and Trust
- Right-click the **Active Directory Domains and Trusts** label in the tree view and select "Properties"
- Go to the "UPN Suffixes" tab
- Add a new suffix

Even though it's *not* email domains, all UPN suffixes should adhere to regular DNS naming conventions.

A number of AD integrated middleware applications like Lync 2010/2013 can automatically add user principal names as SIP addresses, in which case you might want to add a UPN suffix matching the public SIP domain.

In Exchange however, recipient addresses are easily managed with [Email Address Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171(v=exchg.150).aspx). Unless the local domain UPN suffix is causing problems, just leave it be :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The Login Domain is the Active Directory domain, or an Alternate UPN Suffix (AD Domains can have multiple Domain Suffixes). But Since you don't know what it is I ***highly*** recommend you don't touch it.

Comment: lol how else will I learn!??

Comment: Good administrators read manuals and training material. When that falls short they ask their peers. And when that still doesn't measure up they build a test environment in which to experiment. That's how I recommend anyone learn.

Comment: I'm working on a test environment now!